# Change labels text from array in alphabetical order

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, uilabel

I have an array of labels and an array of letters, I want to print each letter in a label in alphabetical order.

I sorted the letters array but I don't know how to sort the labels array.

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var labels: [UILabel]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        wordToLabel()
    }

    let letters = ["B", "E", "C", "D", "A"]

    func wordToLabel() {
        for index in labels.indices {
            let label = labels[index]
            let sortedLetters = letters.sorted { $0 < $1 }
            label.text = sortedLetters[index]
            print(sortedLetters)
        }
    }

}
```

Can I do this without using `UITableView`?

Comment: Why do you want to sort label objects?  If you assign sorted text to them in order they should appear sorted.  Other than sorting the same letters each time through the loop, what's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: @PhillipMills currently the letters appear unsorted

Comment: Maybe, adding tags to labels and then sorting them via tags would help?

Comment: Do the labels in your view appear in the `labels` array in the correct order?  If not, the easy fix is to correct them in the storyboard.

Comment: @PhillipMills you're right the problem comes from the labels array which is unsorted yet, how can I sort it?

Comment: Sorting is kind of a waste when you can arrange them in the outlet collection however you want to begin with.

Comment: Yeah I kind of thought the outlet would arrange them in the correct order by itself, is there a way to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely make sure that the labels are in the correct order. Except of that you could do something like this:

```
let letters = ["B", "E", "C", "D", "A"]

func wordToLabel() {
    let sortedLetters = letters.sorted()
    let sortedLabels = labels.sorted { $0.frame.origin.y < $1.frame.origin.y }

    for (index, label) in sortedLabels.enumerated() {
        label.text = sortedLetters[index]
    }
}
```

Comment: `$0.frame.origin.y < $1.frame.origin.y` was what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If we assume your `labels` array is in the correct order, then you can do this:

```
let letters = ["B", "E", "C", "D", "A"]

func wordToLabel() {
  let sortedLetters = letters.sorted()
  for (index, label) in labels.enumerated() {
    label.text = sortedLetters[index]
}
```

Using `labels.enumerated` gives you access to both the index and the item. You can then use `index` to go through `sortedLetters`.

Btw, `sortedLetters` was left outside the loop because you shouldn't sort it multiple times.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the method, I think the problem comes from the fact that the labels array is not in the correct order, which is what I was trying to d o with `for index in labels.indices {, let label = labels[index]`